# Microwave oven RF leakage graph

Tags: matlab, software-defined-radio

[image][image]

I am using WARP V3 board to receive microwave oven leakage. I placed an antenna outside the door of the oven. I plotted a time series absolute received data. The sampling rate of the rx data is 40Mhz. Microwave opeates ar 2.4Ghz centre freq. As plotted, I can see the spikes which are the magnetron emissions. However each magnetron bunch is followed by a random patch of amplified data as u can see the continuous blue plots. I cannot understand what that signifies?

Comment: no, the spikes aren't the only magnetron emissions. All your non-zero signal is, especially the longer periods of high-power emission. How did you come to the conclusion it's only the spikes?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the phase plot of the rx samples. The spiked portion shows a phase change linear, while that of the high-power emissions, I cannot conclude anything

Comment: well, a linear phase change is a *tone*. The others might just be of higher frequency. And looking at the time signal isn't an appropriate way to detect that: maybe try a waterfall diagram.